# How to open new gnome-terminal that launches a command?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I tried this:

> x-terminal-emulator --command="printf 'New terminal emulator is opened for input'"

But it only opens the terminal window without printing anything!

If I tray:

> gnome-terminal --command="printf 'New terminal emulator is opened for input'"

it does nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'printf "New terminal emulator is opened for input\n"; exec bash'
```

Source and more things you may be interested about here: https://superuser.com/a/198022/755698

An alternative is :

```
gnome-terminal   -e 'sh -c "printf \"New terminal emulator is opened for input\n\";sleep 10"'
```

In the first case, the terminal will remain open and wait for commands...In the second it will wait for ten seconds before close...